# "who" or "which"?

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns

> Among these boys, I know ____ is your brother.

Which relative pronoun, 'who' or 'which' will be appropriate here.
In my opinion, ' who' sounds good here, but if we selecting something or someone from a group we must use 'which'.
Would you please explain it, I will be thankful!

Comment: Both **"who"** and **"which one"** are acceptable but **"who"** is more common. And I would definitely place the preposition at the end and I would consider using **"Of"** instead of **"Among"**. **"Of these boys, I know who *(which one)* your brother is"**

Comment: As sovereignsun pointed out, [subject-auxiliary inversion doesn't occur in an embedded clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127060/help-explaining-where-am-i-vs-where-i-am). So it should be, "who your brother is". But there is no preposition moved here.

Comment: Among is wrong here. A grammar mistake. Of the three boys, I know who your brother is. Boys are people so who.

Comment: @Lambie I don't understand you objection to "among". It is perfectly normal to use it with people. *Who do you know among the people coming for lunch?*, is quite alright.

Comment: I, too, want to ask the same thing.Is using 'among' here grammatically incorrect? @Lambie, would you please explain this.

Comment: There is no reason to use among here.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that **which one** is actually more common than **who** in that particular construction, which begins "Among these boys..."  When referring to one of several, we tend to use **which**, even when people are involved.

> I know who your brother is, since I've met him on a number of
>   occasions, and so, of the people shown in this photo, I can easily identify
>   **which one** he is.

"I can easily identify which one is *him*"  would also be heard quite often.